# io.dropwizard.metrics per webapp in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, dropwizard, metrics

I have a tomcat deployment with multiple(of the same) webapp deployed to it.

I'm looking to get metrics at webapp level via JMX.

So when I'm looking at jconsole

I'm looking for something like:

```
com.orgName
              /webapp1
                /timer-metric1
                /timer-metric2
              /webapp2
                /timer-metric1
                /timer-metric2
```

I'm having trouble getting this per web app.
I've tried:

```
final JmxReporter reporter = JmxReporter.forRegistry(metricsRegistry).inDomain("com.orgName=/getContextName(),Type=TestBean,Name=com.orgName.TestBean")
).build();
```

Anyone know of any way to accomplish this using metrics.dropwizard.io?

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured it out overriding the createName method

```
        ObjectNameFactory objectNameFactory = new ObjectNameFactory() {
        @Override
        public ObjectName createName(String type, String domain, String name) {
            ObjectName objectName = null;
            StringBuilder nameString = new StringBuilder();
            nameString.append(domain + ":");
            nameString.append("Context=").append("/").append(getContextName()).append(",");

            nameString.append("Type=").append(type).append(",");
            nameString.append("Name=").append(name);
            try {
                objectName= new ObjectName(nameString.toString());
            } catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return objectName;
        }
    };

    final JmxReporter reporter = JmxReporter.forRegistry(metricsRegistry)
            .inDomain("com.orgName")
            .createsObjectNamesWith(objectNameFactory)
            .build();

    reporter.start();
```